# POST Request twice

Tags: rest, http, post

> How does doing the same post request twice create duplicate for the same resource. 
>   From what I learnt and understood, 
>   whenever someone does

```
POST  api/users/reg
```

I must register the user and create the resource URL for the specific user.

Now if someone tries to register with same data on the given api, how is it supposed to create a duplicate resource.  It would respond with an error showing that the username is already taken.

Answer (score 2):

Rethink your API design. The resource type users may have many users with unique resource id.

```
       api/users/reg/:userId
```

This way you can post any number of users given the id is different each time.